# Sql query to display data from table A and data from table B where parent_id of table A is found in table B using join

Tags: mysql

USING MySQL.

I have two tables. Table A, and Table B.

Table A has some values that has an ID related to Table B. this id is identified as crm_field in table A and parent_id in table B.

i tried doing this query.

```
select * 
from tableA inner join tableB ON tableA.crm_field=tableB.parent_field 
WHERE tableA.id = '75' AND 
      tableA.category != 'null' AND 
      tableA.category != 'No Category'
```

my expected result is that the data from tableA that met the where requirements will display along with that of tableB that holds the parent_id equivalent to that of the crm_field in tableA.

actual result is tableB being displayed with the exception of the parent_id that holds a value. also it seems that it queried when crm_field = 0 and parent_id = 0, when i want it to query when crm_field has an actual value like 22 that is also found in parent_id. tried doing this instead:

```
select * 
from tableA inner join tableB ON tableA.crm_field=tableB.parent_field 
WHERE tableA.id = '75' AND 
      tableA.category != 'null' AND 
      tableA.category != 'No Category' AND 
      tableA.crm_field != '0'
```

but it only showed the data from tableB that i needed to add to tableA.

is there any way to do this using a join query?

if not i might as well do a double query.

thanks

Sample output:

```
tableA  
id|name|crm_field|category  
0|dog|0|hi  
1|cat|22|hi  
2|bear|0|null|  


tableB  
id|name|parent_id|  
0|wild|22|  
1|foo|0|
```

display should be something like this:

```
0|dog|0|hi  
1|cat|22|hi  
2|wild|22
```

-if this is even possible?

to get to the point what i'm trying to accomplish here is this:

crm_field has some values.

but if the query sees 22 or 21 or both in crm_field it should then display the corresponding value that is found in tableB.

for know i did this if crm_field == 21 or 22 it will do another query to add the corresponding values to an array. but i want to accomplish this with less code as possible thus i was experimenting with join.

Comment: sorry about that. using mysql

Comment: Are you purposely querying against the string 'null' or did you mean to actually check for nulls?

Comment: Also, can you show the sample output you want from your query? It is a bit hard to understand your question as written.

Comment: querying against the string null.

Comment: Yikes! That's gonna cause you a world of trouble one day.

Comment: really? why? please explain. also added the output. i'm starting to think i'm better of doing a double query instead.

Comment: Well for one thing, why re-invent the null value that MySQL already has built into it? No idea what you mean by double query.

Comment: by double query i meant by using an if statement to run another query when a certain field is found on the first query.the null value that MySQL already has built <- explain please?

Comment: use `tableA.category is not null` (Don't put null in quotes)

Comment: never knew that statement exists, true i might have trouble if the user decided to name a category "null". thanks for that info.

Comment: Also, in database programming 'null' and null are two VERY different concepts.

Comment: now that you mention it when putting null inside quotation it is read as a string while without the quotations it is then interpreted as empty. and i quess to check for null it it best to use that statement you have said.

Comment: empty or unknown. Can you try to clean up your question some more? I've read it 10 times and still have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: what do you mean by unknown? could there be such thing as an unknown value? edited the question.

Comment: This discussion is getting a bit long for StackOverflow. In database terms a null value can mean either that there is no value, or that the value is unknown (and thus not entered). You should be able to find more if you Google Database and Null.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Can you just explain in plain english what you are trying to do instead of explaining it in terms of your data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `UNION` would get you the output for your given inputs

```
SELECT  id, name, crmfield
FROM    TableA
WHERE   category != 'null'
UNION ALL
SELECT  a.id, b.name, a.crmfield
FROM    TableA AS a
        INNER JOIN TableB AS b ON b.parent_id = a.crm_field
WHERE   parent_id != '0'
```

but there are several problems with your table design (as already mentioned by JohnFx)

- You should never store a `'null'` string value in any database.
- It is much easier (to me at least) to have your foreign keys named as the primary keys they link to. There's no way to know that `parent_id` is linked to `crm_field`. I would suggest to rename `TableB.parent_id` to `TableB.crm_field` making that link clear.
- You don't want the `TableB.foo` record returned in your result. That strikes me as odd. I can imagine that you only want some parts of a relationship returned but here you seem to have attached some special meaning to `0` as foreign key.

Comment: yes i only need to retrieve data from table that holds either 22 or 21 as their parent_id provided that crm_field contains 22 or 21 if not then tableb should not be retrieved at all. From now on i will not use 'null' as part of a condition in sql since it is bound to be rather dangerous. thank you for this i will try it now.